# Receive and Read JsonString on Express NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send a jsonstring to my server from client. I'm pretty sure I'm sending it OK, But i can't seem to figure out how to read it on server-side. The variable 'sendJSONString' is what I'm trying to send. I've seen many examples where the data is sent in the URL and then extracted. But I'd really rather not do that.

On Client Side i have this code:

```
module.exports = function sendAuthToServer(retVal, _userName, _AUTHKey){
var sendJSONString = JSON.stringify({userName:_userName, AUTHKey:_AUTHKey});
var gotData = [];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('/AUTH'));
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        gotData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    retVal(gotData);
    }
    else {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(sendJSONString);
}
```

On Server Side i have this.

```
module.exports = function giveQueryList(app){
app.get('/AUTH', function(req, res) {

    res.json('ServerResponse');
    console.log(req.ip, req); 
});
}
```

app is using express and is set up like this

```
//CONFIG ROUTER/SERVER
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));//MAKE CONTENT IN VIEWS     FOLDER AVAILABLE TO CLIENT
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8888);
//USE MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the data with a GET HTTP verb. Try changing that to POST or PUT (you'll need to adjust your express route accordingly).

If not done already, you should use middleware like `body-parser` to parse the information send by the client. Then, you can access the information posted/puted by the client on the `req.body` object.